# Function induction contradiction

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [0,+\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a function that verifies this condition : 
$\forall x \ge 0  ~~, ~~2f(x) = f(3x) $ .

1- Prove that : $~~\forall x \ge 0 ~~,~~ \forall\textbf{ n}\in \mathbb{Z} ~~~~; ~~~~~~f(x) = 2^{\textbf{-n}}f(3^{\textbf{n}}x) ~~.$

I tried to use induction which means that I have to prove that : $~~\forall x \ge 0 ~~,~~ \forall\textbf{ n}\in \mathbb{Z} ~~~~; ~~~~~~f(x) = 2^{\textbf{-n+1}}f(3^{\textbf{n+1}}x)$

assuming that : $~~\forall x \ge 0 ~~,~~ \forall\textbf{ n}\in \mathbb{Z} ~~~~; ~~~~~~f(x) = 2^{\textbf{-n}}f(3^{\textbf{n}}x) ~~$   is true .

which means that:  $~~~~~~2^{\textbf{-n}}f(3^{\textbf{n}}x) = 2^{\textbf{-n+1}}f(3^{\textbf{n+1}}x)$

which implies : $ ~~~~f(3^{\textbf{n}}x) = 2f(3^{\textbf{n+1}}x)  ~~\rightarrow ~~f(x)=2f(3x)$  $~~~$

and that's a contradition because of the definition of $f$ 
:  $~~2f(x) = f(3x) ~~$      isn'it ?

Comment: You have made one tiny mistake: $-(n+1)\neq -n+1$. So you actually have to show that $f(x)=2^{-n-1}f(3^{n+1}x)$.

Comment: Why do you write $n$ in bold type face?

Answer (score 2):

You've made an error.  Note that $-(n+1)\ne-n+1$.  That is where those numbers come in as contradictions.  Instead, notice that we don't even need to use induction the way you've done it:

$$f(x)=2^{-n}f(3^nx)$$

Refer to the functional definition of the function to see that $f(3^nx)=2^{-1}f(3^{n+1}x)$ for all $n,x$.  Thus,

$$f(x)=2^{-n}f(3^nx)=2^{-n-1}f(3^{n+1}x)$$

Comment: This is perfectly adequate, though it seems to me that you are essentially still using induction with this argument.

Comment: @infinitylord I am, but I don't think I was using it the way the OP was.  I just wanted to see if I could make a clearer way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$g(x) = |x|^{-ln(2)/ln(3)}f(x)$$
Note that this implies that $g(x)$ is periodic with period $3$. I.e.: $$g(3x) = g(x)$$
Then,
$$f(3^nx) = |3^nx|^{ln(2)/ln(3)}g(3^nx) = 2^n|x|^{ln(2)/ln(3)}g(x) = 2^nf(x)$$
Or,
$$f(x) = 2^{-n}f(3^nx)$$

This technique also does not require $n$ to be an integer.